# Angular JS + append items in ddl

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to append an item inside my dll by targetting its ng-class after a save function like this but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, I am new to AngularJs, please kindly advice:

**My DDL:**

```
<productbatchselectorcreate-dropdown ng-class="batch-{{item.productId}}" name="productBatch" id="{{item.productId}}" ng-model="item.productBatchId" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" class="ui-select2"></productbatchselectorcreate-dropdown>
```

**Directive:**

```
 $scope.save = function () {
             $scope.batch.productId = productId;
             productService.addBatch($scope.batch)
            .success(function (data) {
             $('.batch-' + productId).append(new Option(data.name, data.productBatchId, false, false)); 
             $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
           })
     };
```

Comment: This seems like a bunch of bad approaches on how to use Angular all wrapped up into one little example. Maybe it would help to include the whole directive example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong direction.  Using jQuery to modify your DOM directly usually is not a good approach with Angular.  Your drop down list options should be bound to some value on the scope (I'm not sure what that is though for your directive).  Instead of modifying the DOM with jQuery, you want to add the new object to the scope value that the drop down items are bound.

I made a quick example showing how this works in a simple select http://plnkr.co/edit/jdCzqy3LZ5UXfskGdUMr?p=preview

Since you're using a custom directive though, I'm guessing you're creating the options using an ng-repeat in your directive template.  If so, the same applies, whatever you're repeating over, the scope object for that should be modified, not the DOM directly.